# ms access 2010 back end returning different values depending on which front-end machine is used

Tags: ms-access-2010

database has back-end, accessed from approx 10 front-end machines.  One field in subscriptions table has format "yyyy/yyyy", and it gets its value from the default value of that field eg "2017/2018".  One machine has started storing this field as "0.9995044" which is the number resulting from 2017 divided by 2018 stored as text.
There was an office move at the end of January, on-going hardware linking etc, problem began on 6th February 2017.  Other machines are processing the new records correctly.

Comment: Obviously, somewhere in your code or queries you store or update the value as a number calculation and not as text. So study your frontend.

Comment: Is this a split design? Are these 10 machines each running a local copy of the same frontend? Or are these 10 different frontends?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I will check the machine which is causing the problem, and see if something has been added to that frontend to cause the problem.  I would have said that all frontends carried the same processing for the subscriptions, which is why I cannot understand the problem, but obviously they cannot be.